# Can anybody please explain how sas is solving this code?

Tags: if-statement, sas, filtering

One quick question: why does sas solve the following code

```
data prova_2;
input id_2 $ age_2;
datalines;
zz 22
zz 22
zz 22
zz 23
xx 22
xx 24
aa 25
;
run;

data prova_2;
set prova_2;
if id_2="zz" then do; if age_2=23; end;
run;
```

by outputting the following table?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuMON.png)

I would instead expect it to output just one single line, ie, line 1, the one with id_2="zz" and age_2=23.
Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running the subsetting IF only on SOME of the observations.

So all observations where ID_2 is not zz will also continue to the end of the data step and be written out.

So you are doing the equivalent of

```
if (id_2='zz') and (age_2 ne 23) then DELETE;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't code an explicit OUTPUT statement, then there is an implied OUTPUT statement at the bottom of the DATA step.  So your code is equivalent to:

```
data prova_3;
  set prova_2;
  if id_2="zz" then do;
    if age_2=23; 
  end;
  output ;
run;
```

One way to achieve your desired output would be to add an OUTPUT statement inside the DO loop:

```
data prova_3;
  set prova_2;
  if id_2="zz" then do;
    if age_2=23; 
    output ;
  end;
run;
```

Or just use a single subsetting IF:

```
data prova_3;
  set prova_2;
  if id_2="zz" and age_2=23; 
run;
```